# Heroku DNS configuration to support Heroku common runtime infra returns an error

Tags: http, heroku, https, dns

After getting a notice from Heroku about "DNS configuration updates to support Heroku Common Runtime infrastructure improvements", I updated my DNS, but it is not working.

Before it was app-awesomeapp.herokuapp.com and it goes through cloudflare.com and my website uses **https**://app.mywebsite.com and it was working.
Now I added a new DNS target, something like this:

```
computational-somename-mudzfo2ewpx443ilkthxxxxxw.herokudns.com
```

It returns a host error when I go to app.mywebsite.com.

How can I fix this problem? The new configuration setup must be done by July 31, 2021